# Inject JavaScript with jQuery at runtime into WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have desktop application with WebBrowser control and try to inject JavaScript into loaded page.

For this I added two script elements:

```
private static void AddJQueryElement(HtmlElement head)
{
    HtmlElement scriptEl = head.Document.CreateElement("script");
    IHTMLScriptElement jQueryElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
    jQueryElement.src = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js";

    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);           
}

private static void AddScriptElement(HtmlElement head)
{
    HtmlElement scriptEl = head.Document.CreateElement("script");
    IHTMLScriptElement myScriptElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
    myScriptElement.src = @"file:///c:\JScript.js";
    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

how you can see first is reference to jQuery because I use it in my script. When I try to invoke function from my script using `_webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript` WebBrowser throws 
Script Error :"Object expected". and points to the line where i try to use jQuery (`var tags = $("Body").find("*");`).

How can I prevent this error?

Another interesting thing: if I add something like `alert("hello");` to start of my function all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't got correct answer, but have solved the problem by using local copy of jquery.min.js.

Comment: Hey Orsol, can you tell me how you connected to the webpage. I mean how your application connects to the page. I really want to do that but can't figure it out how to do that.

Comment: I load page in a WebBrowser control.

Comment: can you please include your full code ? i am getting $ undefined error. but plain javascript working.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you aren't specifying your script to run on load.  alert("hello") is buying that time needed to download the script/finish building the HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```